# Curve grades fx (list operation and loops) python

Tags: python, for-loop, nested

I'm trying to put together a fx that I has a user input a list of grades and # of points to curve by. The fx should then add the amount to "curve by" to each test score and then return the avg. In one fx I am able to ask for grades, amt to curve by, and make a list with the original grades and add the amt of points to each grade. In the second fx I can sum the new list (w/out sum fx -important) and then then take and return the avg. Is it possible to put these to together in one fx? For this assignment I can use for/while loops and conditionals.

1). Take list and add points to make a new list

```
grades = [int(x) for x in input("Please enter the grades separated by a space").split()]

c = float(input("Please enter the number of points to curve by: "))

new = [ ]

def addcurve(grades, c):
    for n in grades:
        new.append(n+c)
    return new

print(addcurve(grades, c))

[OUT]: [94.0, 45.0, 78.0, 95.0, 60.0, 74.0]
```

2). Sum the new list and taking avg

```
[IN]:
def sumavg(new):
    total_sum = 0
    for n in new:
        total_sum += n  
        gt = len(new)
        final = total_sum/gt
    return "%.2f" %(final)
```

print("The new average after curving the grades is", sumavg(new))

```
[OUT]: The new average after curving the grades is 74.33
```

If anyone has an insight please let me know!

Thank you!

Cheers,

Rachel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it's bad practice to declare a variable outside a function, that the function uses to store the result of it's operation and return it. Instead, declare `new = []` inside `addcurve()`

Secondly, the function you want is:

```py
def foo(grades, c):
    total_sum = 0
    for n in grades:
        total_sum += n+c
    final = total_sum/len(grades)
    return "%.2f" %(final)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! As for the variables outside fx, it was just what I was shown in class. Appreciate the insight!

Comment: Actually if I don't define new outside of the fx it won't store it

Comment: The correct way to do is to define `new = []` inside the function and return it. To store the result, you simply call the function like this `new = addcurve(grades, c)` and then `print(new)`. The rest remains as is.